# Error when populating DropDownList with database data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

In my view I have a DropDownList which I populate with database data. But when I run it I get an error I don't really understand:

"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DdlBagTypes'."

I'm not sure how to do this but I looked up various solutions and this is how I do it:

**Function to get data from database:**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getBagelTypes()
    {
        return (from t in Db.BagelType.AsEnumerable()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = t.Name,
                    Value = t.BagelTypeId.ToString(),
                }).AsEnumerable();             
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["LstBagels"] = DbO.getBagels();
        TempData["LstTypeOptions"] = DbO.getBagelTypes();
        Session["OrderCount"] = OrderCount;

        return View();
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model BestelBagels.Models.Bagel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

var LstBagels = ViewData["LstBagels"] as List<BestelBagels.Models.Bagel>;
var LstTypeOptions = TempData["LstTypeOptions"] as IEnumerable<SelectList>;
var OrderCount = Session["OrderCount"];
}

@Html.DropDownList("DdlBagTypes", (SelectList)LstTypeOptions)
```

Comment: This one gets me all the time. Check to see if `LstTypeOptions` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of TempData use ViewData to pass data to the view:

```
ViewData["LstTypeOptions"] = DbO.getBagelTypes();
```

and inside your view:

```
var LstTypeOptions = ViewData["LstTypeOptions"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DdlBagTypes", LstTypeOptions)
```

Also notice the correct type being casted `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is what your `getBagelTypes` function returns. In your example you were attempting to cast to `IEnumerable<SelectList>` which obviously returns `null` because that's not what you stored inside the TempData.

But personally I would throw away this ViewData stuff and introduce a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LstTypeOptions { get; set; }

    public string SelectedBagel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LstBagels { get; set; }

    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
}
```

that I would populate in my controller action and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.LstTypeOptions = DbO.getBagelTypes();
    model.LstBagels = DbO.getBagels();
    model.OrderCount = OrderCount;

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally I would make my view strongly typed to the view model and use strongly typed helpers:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOption, Model.LstTypeOptions)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedBagel, Model.LstBagels)
...
<div>You have a total of @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.OrderCount) orders</div>
```